# I want to pass some text into the textfield but something wrong....idk why print() is work

Tags: swift, ios11, swift4, xcode9

**swift4 Xocode9**

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Contextual closure type '() -> Void' expects 0 arguments, 
        // but 1 was used in closure body

        let str:String = ""
        self.finalresulter.text = str
        self.finalresulter.text = "\($0.map{$0.content.title})"
    }

    print($0.map { $0.content.title},",",$0.map { $0.content.subtitle},","
        ,$0.map { $0.content.body},","
        ,$0.map { $0.trigger!})

}
```

please help...how to fix..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue appears to be identical to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48238971/how-can-i-put-these-print-text-into-textfield). In order not to replicate existing answer I gave there, I would only mention the second part, which would look like:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests { requests in 

    // Textfield assignment here ...

    print(requests.map { $0.content.title},",",requests.map { $0.content.subtitle},","
        ,requests.map { $0.content.body},","
        ,requests.map { $0.trigger!})
}
```

But, unless you explicitly want to print everything on one line, this print should be better replaced with regular `for` loop (or at least a `forEach` method):

```
// 1
for item in requests {
    print(item.content.title, item.content.subtitle, item.content.body)
}
// 2
requests.forEach {
    print($0.content.title, $0.content.subtitle, $0.content.body)
}
```

Comment: Thanks again,that's what exactly i want
do you know how to take timeInterval this value out?

<UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger: 0x1c00337c0; repeats: NO, timeInterval: 1000.000000>

i try this but fail...
requests.map { $0.trigger.timeInterval}

Comment: unfortunately, these are two different objects. `$0.trigger` in your case is [UNNotificationTrigger](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationtrigger) while `timeInterval` property only exists on [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/untimeintervalnotificationtrigger), which is a subclass of the former where this property was introduced. You can try to downcast that trigger to `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` and try to grab `timeInterval` property, but no guaranties it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
notificatecontent.text = "\($0.map{$0.content.title})"
```

Comment: Thanks Madhur, but i still got the error:
Reference to property 'notificatecontent' in closure requires explicit 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit

Comment: and i follow the xcode instruction try to make like this
self.notificatecontent.text = "\($0.map{$0.content.title})"

and i got another error
Thread 8: signal SIGABRT.....
T_T

Comment: i can build successeed But when i click the function button ,got this err Thread 8: signal SIGABRT.
&
UITextView.text must be used from main thread only

Comment: You need to dispatch the code back onto the main thread using `DispatchQueue.main.async { // Code to run }`

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.notificatecontent.text = "\($0.map{$0.content.title})" as String
            }

and i got this err ..Expression type 'String' is ambiguous without more context