# how can i put these print text into Textfield?

Tags: ios11, swift4, xcode9

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests {

    DispatchQueue.main.async{//Contextual closure type '() -> Void' expects 0 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body
     let str:String = ""
     self.finalresulter.text = str
     self.finalresulter.text = "\($0.map{$0.content.title})"
     }
    }
```

Comment: the print() is work in Xcode, but not work when trying to put into textfield
 

*************print($0.map { $0.content.title},",",$0.map { $0.content.subtitle},",",$0.map { $0.content.body},",",$0.map { $0.trigger!})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `$0` inside `async { }` closure. This closure expects no arguments, which means using `$0` argument shortcut is invalid.

You are evidently attempting to refer to `requests` array from `getPendingNotificationRequests` callback. The reason you can't by using `$0` is that it's screened by `DispatchQueue.main.async{ ... }` closure with no arguments:

Try this:

```
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests { requests in
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            let str:String = ""
            self.finalresulter.text = str
            self.finalresulter.text = "\(requests.map{$0.content.title})"
        }
    }
```

The rule for `$0` claims that **`$0` always refers to current scope**. Thus, to access closure argument from nested closure, that argument must be named (`requests` in the above code).